# Usage of the expression "to go bad"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say "weather goes bad" meaning that it no longer keeps fine?

Answer (score 1):

*Go bad* is usually used of food or other organic matter decaying and becoming infected.

The weather *turns bad, changes for the worse* or *deteriorates.*

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.